# Why does this forms authentication require double login sometimes?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to implement forms authenication in ASP.NET 2010 through a login page and a database table of usernames and passwords.

Some of the time some of the users must authenicate twice, which is getting annoying to those users and they are complaining.

In the web.config I have

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="WebFormLogon.aspx" defaultUrl="WebformHomepage.aspx"/>
</authentication>
```

In the code behind file after validating the password and username I do the following:

```cs
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
      username,
      DateTime.Now,
      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(60),
      isPersistent,
      userData,
      FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    // Encrypt the ticket.
    string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

    // Create the cookie.
    Response.Cookies.Add(new System.Web.HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));

    string redirectpage = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, isPersistent);
    Response.Redirect(redirectpage);
```

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue and determine the difference between the different behaviors?

Answer (score 0):

what athentication level do you have set in IIS for that site?  I'm wondering if you have integrated and anon which might cause the dual login you're mentioning.  Basically your users might be getting prompted by IIS and then by your app.